# smartgwt styling

Tags: css, gwt, fonts, smartgwt

I'm using smart gwt 2.4 and I was wondering if anyone knows a simple way to change the font size for all text displayed in an application. I'm using Simplicity theme, and the default size is really small. I'm sure I just need to edit some css file, but I would appreciate if someone could help with this.

Comment: did you find an answer? because I have the same question

Answer (score 2):

Use firebug in firefox, this will show you which CSS is effecting the font, and which file it's in. Then change this accordingly.

Comment: That works for things like labels, but it's a little more difficult for text boxes and the : between the label and a text box.